# How to link directly to a Google+ Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

If I start a Google+ Hangout, is there anyway to send my friends a link directly to that Hangout post? I couldn't find any options.

So I have to send people a link to my profile, and let them click on the join hangout button. I prefer not to do that since the hangout post may be buried by my other updates.

Comment: I guess this is somehow related to my question. I started a hangout on my phone, but I'm unable to figure out how to access it from a desktop browser: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/access-old-google-hangout-from-web-browser

Comment: Nik Graf's answer is the new solution (June 2014) to this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

When you create a hangout, just copy the URL at the top of the pop-up window that opens up. Send it to anyone you want. They need to sign in with a Gmail account (that is associated with a Google+ profile) and they will be added to the hangout.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried (intuitively) but it simply does not work. Maybe it worked in 2011, but in 2013 a new browser window using this Hangout URL just stays empty. Maybe the JS code used in current Hangouts depends on the window name.

Answer (score 13):

Google build an URL exactly for the purpose of starting a Hangout video call session and let others join by a link you share with them.

Simply visit: http://hangouts.google.com/start

Visiting this link starts a Hangout video call session and shows you the link you can share.

[image: Video call: Link / Send an Invite]

Comment: Huge tahnks :-)

Answer (score 4):

Currently (May 2013) this is only possible using a detour:

You have to create a Google+ event (place it in the far future, like 2050) and activate a hangout for that event. This event-attached hangout comes with a perma-link of the following form:

```
https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/xyz3127474c86ff55efc18836b4335a71f82dxyz
```

This can be used to directly jump into the hangout.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add an existing hangout to a new event; an event always creates its own, personal hangout. So this method is not suitable to create perma-links for already existing hangouts.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer possible either.  As of mid-2016, Google Events will sometimes at some interval, change the Hangout link associated with a future-dated event. Looks like this may only be possible with paid Google Apps accounts

Answer (score 3):

There are two links that both start a Video Hangout and give you a popup with hangout address to share

- https://g.co/hangout
- http://hangouts.google.com/start

Answer (score 2):

While you're in the hangout, you can click "Invite" and put individual names in the field. They'll then receive a notification with a link.

Comment: This works for people who are already in my circle. However if I start a public hangout, I'd like to be able to post a URL somewhere else(e.g. Twitter, Facebook etc).

Answer (score 2):

Hangouts has now been updated to include link sharing - a URL can be generated through which users can join.

To use it on Android or iOS, you'll need version 11 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I create a permanent event by setting an end date far into the future.
When I actually join the hangout from within that event, I am offered to copy a permanent link to the hangout for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google+ profile your number id should be like this 
`https://plus.google.com/********` 
Which can be seen from Profile section in Your Google Plus page.
now use the number `********` to create following link

`https://hangouts.google.com/?action=chat&pi=********`

People can find you on Hangouts using this link without knowing your Gmail address. To use this link on Android they need to use "request desktop site" option on Android browser.

you can use link shortener sites like `https://bit.do` to customize this link to `bit.do/*****` using small letters `a,b,c,..`. for `*****` . Just note that link is sensitive to small and big letters.