# Create direct link to Google Hangouts chat

Tags: google-hangouts

I need to create a link to open one particular Hangouts chat (not [videocall](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/how-to-link-directly-to-a-google-hangout)). It is possible to open a chat in a separate window from the main Google+ page, but the URL of that window (something like `https://talkgadget.google.com/u/0/talkgadget/_/frame?v=1395695842&hl=ru#tgtn_c71vh1`) can't be opened again.

Is it possible to get a permanent URL?

Answer (score 11):

**As of April 2018**, It actually *is* possible to create URL to link to a chat with a specific person. (But who knows when Google will break these given the [ongoing incoherence of their messaging applications](https://medium.com/@fabian.kutschera/googles-communication-strategy-duo-allo-hangouts-confusion-1b41115523b7)…)

First, you'll need to know that person's [Gaia ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028322/how-to-look-up-user-information-from-google-gaia-id) (an internal ID used by Google Hangouts and Google Plus)

- If you're looking for your *own* Gaia ID, login to your Google account and visit [`https://plus.google.com/me`](https://plus.google.com/me). This will redirect to a URL of the form `https://plus.google.com/1XXXXXXXXXX`. The long number at the end of the URL is your Gaia ID. (If you don't have a Google Plus profile, it'll be an error page, but it'll still have the correct Gaia ID.)
- If you're looking for someone *else's* Gaia ID, search for them on Google Plus. If you can find a URL of the form `https://plus.google.com/u/0/1XXXXXXXXXXXX/...` associated with their profile, you've got their Gaia ID.
- If you use the reverse-engineered [purple-hangouts library to use Hangouts in an instant messenger desktop client](https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts), then the "About" or "Info" box for a contact should show you their Gaia ID.

Anyway, once you've got someone's Gaia ID, it's pretty straightforward to create the correct URL to start a Hangout with them. Simply replace `1XXXXXXXXXXXX` below with that user's Gaia ID:

```
https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/1XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Any insight on link format for a group chat?

Comment: Group chats…? Those are easy: they have links like `https://hangouts.google.com/group/Lrjad6ru9e806l69AlpHaNuMer1c` which you can create from the web interface itself. Likewise for group video calls, with links like `/call/number`.

Comment: If you have a Vanity "Custom" Profile URL, then it won't show your Gaia ID.  To get your Gaia ID, you can use the Google API Explorer here:  https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get   Type in your Custom Name (e.g. "+MyName") and ask for the "id" field, and it will return your Gaia ID.

Comment: THIS WORKS!! FINALLY!

Answer (score 3):

As stated before by [@Dan Leski](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/184813/dan-lenski)

1. you'll need to know that person's Gaia ID (an internal ID used by Google).

   I have added [a detailed answer to an existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442288/64556) in which I describe **how to retrieve the Gaia ID using the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)**.
   TL;DR: Request `metadata` in the `personFields`, by using `people.connections.list` resources for your contacts, or the `people/get` resource for yourself.
2. Once you've got someone's Gaia ID, it's pretty straightforward to create the correct URL to start a Hangout with them. Simply replace 1XXXXXXXXXXXX below with that user's Gaia ID:

   https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/1XXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know of right now to find Gaia ID is actually to go to [get.google.com/albumarchive](https://get.google.com/albumarchive) and the 21 numbers that reveal itself once you go to Album Archive will be your own and you can use it.

Once you get the id, it easy to create your hangout link.

https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/[Gaia ID]

where [Gaia Id] = 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (21 digits)

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

No, at this time it's not possible to get a permanent URL to a Google Hangouts "chat" but it's possible to get a permanent URL to a Google Hangout "chat history" and open the chat from the linked web page.

## Explanation

Google Hangouts "chats" could be accessed from several places (Gmail, Google+ Chrome Extension, Chrome App, Hangouts web app, mobile apps) but none of them offer a way to get a permanent URL for a Google Hangouts chat.

But Google Hangouts "chats" history have a permanent URL. From the corresponding page the chat could be opened.

To get the URL

1. go to http://mail.google.com/mail/0/u/#chats
2. locate the chat history of interest and open it.
3. copy the URL from the web browser's address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to something like `https://hangouts.google.com/call/cywnzqtjadjwhl55kfr5euvanyb`.
Click on `Join Hangout` and then send the link to your partner.

Link as `https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/cywnzqtjadjwhl55kfr5euvanyb` should work as well.

You may play with the address as the security feature here is the randomness of address.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019, you can find someone's Gaia ID by going to a chat, starting up the developer tools, then look at the network log for a querypresence POST request; the URL may look like this:

https://chat-pa.clients6.google.com/chat/v1/presence/querypresence?key=blahblahblah&alt=protojson

The post data contains something like this (mangled):

```
[[[44,3,"chat_frontend_20190321.06_p1",1553297518],
["lcsw_hangouts_7D87E9D6","17D2A8EEB9EE1DD8"],null,"en"],
[["106512922239035206222"],["109501794533344715333"]],[2,3,10]]
```

The long numbers are Gaia ids; yours and your chat partner's.